# Deploy from CI/CD via HELM to external Kubernetes cluster with limited rights

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rbac

I understand that I can copy my `.kube/config` to my CI/CD server, or just name the `ServiceAccount` to allow my CD pipeline to use HELM for deployment.

However, what if I want to allow deployment via Helm, but restrict a lot of other access, like:

- reading data from pods or a deployed database
- port-forward services

... so basically accessing all data in the cluster, except for stateless Docker containers deployed via Helm.

Would it be possible to create a new `ClusterRole` with limited rights? What verbs in a `ClusterRole` does Helm need at least to function properly?

What rights does Helm need at the least?

Comment: Hello @rStorms. So you want to grant Helm a cluster scoped permissions for creating Deployments only, right?

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to what your Helm chart is doing to Kubernetes.

`ClusterRoles` can be bound to a particular namespace through reference in a `RoleBinding`. The `admin`, `edit` and `view` default `ClusterRoles` are commonly used in this manner. For more detailed info see [this description](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/rbac/#roles-clusterroles-rolebindings-and-clusterrolebindings). For example `edit` is a default `ClusterRole` which allows read/write access to most objects in a namespace. It does not allow viewing or modifying `Roles` or `RoleBindings`; and granting a user `cluster-admin` access at the namespace scope provides full control over every resource in the namespace, including the namespace itself.

You can also restrict a user's access to a particular namespace by using either the `edit` or the `admin` role. See [this example](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/rbac/#example-grant-a-user-readwrite-access-to-a-particular-namespace).

The permissions strategy could also depend on what objects will be created by the installation. The user will need all access to those API objects that will be managed by helm installations. [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) has this concept explained in more detail with several examples that you could use as a reference. Also, [this source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/plugin/pkg/auth/authorizer/rbac/bootstrappolicy/testdata/cluster-roles.yaml) would be helpful.